# How to change value of state parameters with $transition$.params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I defined `state` with `$stateProvider` as you can see below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').config(stateConfig);

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('baseInformation', {
            parent: 'panel',
            url: 'baseInformation',
            params: {
                backFilters: null
            },
            views: {
                'panel': {
                    templateUrl: 'baseInformation.html',
                    controller: 'BaseInformationController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

In another controller, i use `$state.go('baseInformation', {backFilters: 12})`. now i want to change value of `backFilters` parameters with something like this code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('BaseInformationController', BaseInformationController);

    function BaseInformationController($transition$, CommonUtils) {
        var vm = this;

        // updated question
        CommonUtils.checkParamtersAndLog($transition$);
        $transition$.params().backFilters = 20;

        // updated question
        CommonUtils.checkParamtersAndLog($transition$);
    }
})();
```

but i got this below error:

**TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'backFilters' of object '#'**

I also searched for this problem, but didn't find any way and it is very critical for me.

**UPDATE**

I used from `$transition$.params().backFilters` in a service based on it's value, maybe something like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').factory('CommonUtils', CommonUtils);

    function CommonUtils() {

        var service = {
            checkParamtersAndLog: checkParamtersAndLog
        };

        function checkParamtersAndLog(transition) {
            if(transition.params().backFilters == null) {
                console.log('backFilters is null');
            }
            else {
                console.log('backFilters is not null')
            }
        }

        return service;
    }
})();
```

and want to change `$transition$.params().backFilters` value from controllers.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the parameter directly?  If you want to manipulate that value you should assign it to a variable first and then change that variable.

Comment: dear @BShaps please check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by storing the value of the backFilters param in your CommonUtils service with some setter/getter functions.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').factory('CommonUtils', CommonUtils);

    function CommonUtils() {
        var backFilters = null;

        var service = {
            checkParamtersAndLog: checkParamtersAndLog.
            setBackFilters: setBackFilters,
            getBackFilters: getBackFilters
        };

        function checkParamtersAndLog() {
            if(backFilters == null) {
                console.log('backFilters is null');
            }
            else {
                console.log('backFilters is not null')
            }
        }

        function setBackFilters(backFilterValue) {
            backFilters = backFilterValue;
        };

        function getBackFilters() {
            return backFilters;
        };

        return service;
    }
})();
```

Then you can change your controller like so:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('BaseInformationController', BaseInformationController);

    function BaseInformationController($transition$, CommonUtils) {
        var vm = this;
        CommonUtils.setBackFilters($transition$.params().backFilters);

        // updated question
        CommonUtils.checkParamtersAndLog();
        CommonUtils.setBackFilters(20);

        // updated question
        CommonUtils.checkParamtersAndLog();
    }
})();
```

And if you want to reset the value to null on leaving the state add this to your state provider:

```
onExit: function() { 
    CommonUtils.setBackFilters(null);
}
```